# Google App Script: extract data from a XML file

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, xml-parsing

I need to pull this XML structure to a Google spreadsheet,

```
<directory>
    <fieldset>
        <field id="displayName">Display name</field>
        <field id="firstName">First name</field>
    </fieldset>
    <employees>
        <employee id="200">
            <field id="displayName">Donald Duck</field>
            <field id="firstName">Donald</field>
        </employee>
    </employees>
</directory>
```

I've pulled all the `<field id>`, but I need just the `<employee id>` and I don't know how to do, pardon me I haven't any knowledge on XML so please help me.

```
function ImportXML() {

   var url = "https://api.Fake.com/employees/directory";
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);



    var xml = response.getContentText();
    var doc = XmlService.parse(xml);
    var root = doc.getRootElement();


    logChildren(doc.getRootElement().getChildren());


 function logChildren(elements){


    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];  

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {

    var range = sheet.getRange(1,i+1);

    range.setValue(elements[i].getText());

    if(elements[i].getContentSize() > 1){
    var children = elements[i].getChildren();

    logChildren(children);
    }
     }
      }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I need to excract the 'employee id'

Answer (score 1):

Check this document regarding [reading a specific node using appscript](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service/element#getchildname)

> **getChild(name)**
>
> Gets the first Element node with the given name and no namespace that
>   is an immediate child of this Element node. If there is no such node,
>   this method returns null.
>
> Parameters
>
> Name  Type    Description name    String  the name of the child Element node
>   Return
>
> Element — the Element node, or null if there is no immediate child
>   Element node with the given name and no namespace

Use this working example as your guide.

```
  function readSpecificNode() {
  var url = 'https://www.w3schools.com/xml/books.xml';
  var xml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(xml);
  var entries = document.getRootElement().getChild('book').getChild('title').getAttribute('lang').getValue();
  Logger.log(entries);
}
```

Just do not forget to change the `url` to your designated xml and the `getChild` element from 'book', 'title' and 'lang' to 'directory', 'employees', 'employee' then setting the `getAttribute` to 'id' so it would fit your desired output.

Comment: var entries = document.getRootElement().getChild('directory').getChild('employees').getChild('employee').getAttribute('id').getValue();

Comment: I got :"TypeError: Cannot call method "getChild" of null. "